# Vue: How to use variable as array key in component binding

Tags: arrays, vue.js, string-interpolation, array-key

How can I use variable array keys for bindings in my custom component? In the following example, title must be 'Title 1 for default settings' if `componenttype` is set to 'default', 'Title 1 for guest settings' if `componenttype` is set to 'guest' etc. I tried to interpolate it in several ways, but nothing worked so far. Any hints?

```
<my-component
    v-for="item in items"
    :id="item.id"
    :title="item['componenttype'].title"     <-- how to interpolate here?
>
</my-component>


...
data() {
   return {
      componenttype: 'default',
      items: [
         { 
            1: {
               default: {
                  title: 'Title 1 for default settings',
               },
               guest: {
                  title: 'Title 1 for guest settings'
               }
            },
            2: {
               default: {
                  title: 'Title 2 for default settings',
               },
               guest: {
                  title: 'Title 2 for guest settings'
               }
            },
         }
      ]
   }
}
...
```

Comment: You have two `default` inside `items`. How to know which one you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array currently contains only one object, with multiple nested objects. It should be:

```
items: [
            {
               default: {
                  title: 'Title 1 for default settings',
               },
               guest: {
                  title: 'Title 1 for guest settings'
               }
            },
            {
               default: {
                  title: 'Title 2 for default settings',
               },
               guest: {
                  title: 'Title 2 for guest settings'
               }
            }
      ]
```

With this the following should work:

```
<my-component v-for="item in items"
    :title="item[componenttype].title"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are making `componenttype` into a string by doing `:title="item['componenttype'].title"`. 
Just do `:title="item[componenttype].title"`

Also check your array syntax, there might be some mistakes there